# How to show cache for product pagination collection page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, pagination

We have created custom category product collection having pagination, but when we add below code it's not working with pagination. When we click next page then it's always showing first page product.

```
<action method="setCacheLifetime">
   <lifetime>3600</lifetime> 
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCacheKeyInfo` needs to include the current page:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/adding-cache-support-to-magento-blocks/

And to get the current page, you can call:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p', 1);
```

Comment: We use create collection using this link http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/